# Remove word from Noklia Windows 8 phone correction dictionary

Tags: windows-8, editing, spell-check, mobile-phone

Accidentally saved a word "Ihope" on Windows 8 Nokia phone. The intended target was "I hope" and I had forgotten the space then mistakenly hit +Ihope on the correction line.

Is there a simple way to remove this entry. This is a common typing/texting error for me and I do not want the lack of space to be accepted.

Comment: Is this the only word you've added to the dictionary?  Because the only info I can find for Windows Phone 8 dictionary is to "reset dictionary", and that seems rather drastic to me.

Comment: You might want to post this in http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/. Please remove this question if you do or flag this one to be moved there.